# What's up with Mioko's speech pattern?

Tags: japanese-language, ojisan-and-marshmallow

Mioko (voiced by Kana Hanazawa) uses some kind of unusual speech pattern which the subtitles translate into vaguely US Southern dialectal English:

[image]
[image]

Specifically, I can hear her using *ora* to refer to herself and ending her sentences with *de gasu* instead of *desu*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_pronouns) says *ora* is an informal pronoun with rural connotations, and [this Google Books result](https://books.google.com/books?id=-3kBAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=japanese+de+gasu&source=bl&ots=abdOz6W0KP&sig=GwbxhTaltjTLAQotu5mYzg0D8lk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw6YSIvYLMAhUYzmMKHZyrDHsQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=japanese%20de%20gasu&f=false) says *de gasu* is a contraction of *de gozarimasu*, a very polite form of *de aru*.

You can hear it for yourself in [Episode 7](http://www.crunchyroll.com/ojisan-and-marshmallow/episode-7-mioko-and-marshmallow-692327) starting around 24 seconds in.

Is Mioko's accent a specific regional accent, or is it just one of those made up bizarre speech patterns that anime specializes in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dreaded TV Tropes has some pretty [good notes on Japanese dialects](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/UsefulNotes/JapaneseDialects).  The use of *ora* instead of *ore* and being used by women in particular is an element of the Tohoku dialect.  It also compares the dialect to US English 'hillbilly' accents, which matches with the subtitling.

It does not list the use of *de gasu* in place of *desu*, but the notes are hardly comprehensive.  Or it could be a personal thing for Mio5.